# jQuery mobile - dynamically switch Select Menu to Multiple

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-select

I want to enable the multiple select when I checked the checkbox, but it doesn't work. How to achieve this using jQuery mobile?

```
<input type="checkbox" id="toggle"/>Toggle Select
<select name="targets" id="targets">
    <option value="0">-----Select an option ----</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
 </select>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggle").on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked') == true){ 
            $("#targets").attr('multiple', true).attr("data-native-menu","false");
        } else {
            $("#targets").attr('multiple',false);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hello. I edited your question. I have separated HTML and JS code snippets so that they have a proper syntax coloring. Also, I've fixed some code styling, indenting. If you have any questions - please, contact me.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<style>
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="checkbox" id="toggle"> Toggle Select
   <select name="targets" id="targets">
         <option value="0">-----Select a option ----</option>
         <option value="1">option 1</option>
         <option value="2">option 2</option>
         <option value="3">option 3</option>
   </select>

  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

       $("#toggle").on('click',function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')==true){ 
         $("#targets").attr('multiple',true).attr("data-native-menu","false");
        }else{
         $("#targets").attr('multiple',false);
        }
      });

  });
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works in jquery ,but not workd in jqeury mobile,  include the jquery mobile css file.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `attr()` function which is good for simple HTML attributes.
However, in the newer versions of jQuery (after 1.6), for element properties like `readonly`, `checked`, `multiple` you need to use jQuery `prop()` function.

Try changing the function:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#toggle").on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).is(':checked') == true){ 
            $("#targets").prop('multiple', true).attr("data-native-menu","false");
        } else {
            $("#targets").prop('multiple',false);
        }
    });
});
```

You can read more about `jQuery.prop()` [here](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

Here is my [JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hvan7saj/) which works.

Comment: I know  it works well in jquery, but it not works in jquery mobile.Thanks .@Yeldar

Comment: Oh, I see. Try using `$('#targets').attr('multiple', 'multiple')`. Isn't it working as well?

Answer (score 0):

Start with data-native-menu="false" in the markup:

```
<label><input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />Toggle Select</label>
<select name="targets" id="targets" data-native-menu="false">
    <option value="0">-----Select an option ----</option>
    <option value="1">option 1</option>
    <option value="2">option 2</option>
    <option value="3">option 3</option>
</select>
```

Then on the checkbox change event, destroy the selectmenu widget, update the multiple prop, and reinitialize it:

```
$("#toggle").on('change', function () {
    $("#targets").selectmenu("destroy").prop('multiple', $(this).is(':checked')).selectmenu();
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hvan7saj/1/)**

If you want the native menu for single select, change the code to:

```
$("#targets").selectmenu("destroy").prop('multiple', $(this).is(':checked')).selectmenu({  nativeMenu: !$(this).is(':checked')});
```

> **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/hvan7saj/2/)**